# How to generate and process multiple checklistboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, dynamic, checklistbox

Gurus,

I've been searching for a clear example on how I can go about processing multiple, varying categories of items with C# in ASP.NET.  The data is similar to the following:

```
Category1 Heading
  Item
  Item
  Item

Category2 Heading
  Item
  Item
  Item
Category3 Heading
  Item
  Item
  Item
```

The category names and items come from a SQL database.  I imagine I'll need one checkboxlist for each category of items and the number of categories is dynamic and will change over time.  Is it possible to create a loop to dynamically build the required checkboxlists and then be able to process them?  I read about maybe using a data repeater as well.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a repeater or a DataGrid.  Occasionally it's easier for me to use a DataGrid and just add rows for each new Category.  Do you have any more specifics on what you're looking to do with it?

You could use a DataGrid and for each category add a new row.  And within that row add Controls.  A less savvy way would be to use a PlaceHolder on the page and just add controls to that.  But I would definitely suggest a DataGrid or looking into the Repeater.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I need to take the data gathered and insert it into the database.  The single checklistbox that I use now works for processing but it does not allow for grouping of the individual items.  I need to group bunches of items and provide a header for them from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this...

Your business object. You may use this as a model you can transform from your 'real' business object or use your business object directly

```
public class BusinessObject
{
    public string Category { get; set; }  //Your category
    public int ID { get; set; }           //Point of data entry and will be return on post
    public string Name { get; set; }      //A friendly name for your users
}
```

Your aspx markup. I'm using a repeater for the categories which just has a `CheckBoxList` in it which will have the actual items. This can be expanded and styled quite a bit.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkboxlist" 
                          runat="server" 
                          DataTextField="Name" 
                          DataValueField="ID" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

A  Place to get your business objects from: Here I just have a member on my codebehind. You should grab this data from your business layer/tier.

```
List<BusinessObject> MyBusinessObjects = new List<BusinessObject>();
```

And your code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Wire up the event to handle when items are bound to the repeater
        this.myRepeater.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(myRepeater_ItemDataBound);
        //Now actually bind the categories to the repeater
        this.myRepeater.DataSource = GetCategories(MyBusinessObjects);
        this.myRepeater.DataBind();
    }

    void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Don't process items that are not item, or alternating item
        if (!(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)) return;
        //Grab a reference to the checkboxlist in our repeater
        CheckBoxList checkboxlist = (CheckBoxList)e.Item.FindControl("checkboxlist");
        //Now put our business objects of that category in it
        checkboxlist.DataSource = GetItemsFromCategory(MyBusinessObjects, (string)e.Item.DataItem);
        checkboxlist.DataBind();
    }
    //Helper to grab categories.
    private IEnumerable<string> GetCategories(IEnumerable<BusinessObject> items)
    {
        return (from i in items
                select i.Category).Distinct();
    }
    //Helper to grab the items in categories.
    private IEnumerable<BusinessObject> GetItemsFromCategory(IEnumerable<BusinessObject> items, string category)
    {
        return (from i in items
                where i.Category == category
                select i);
    }
```

Comment: So it sounds like there's a few options: repeater, listview with template, business objects. Not sure which one is the simplest.

Comment: The wonderful thing about programming is that their are lots of choices. The solution I've suggested here is just one way to do it. Most coders would say go with the solution that is easiest to maintain; not necessarily easiest to build.

Comment: I looked into the datagrid but I'm not sure how I can make it with checkboxes. I need users to select any combination of items that they want and record this info in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know in advance how many items there could be, then you need a display that will not break. The best way to achieve this is by using a ListView with a GroupTemplate:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1364813.aspx/1

Comment: Still trying to figure this one out (I'm fairly new to .NET in general).  I know how many items there will be from the database at page load time, it will not be dynamically changed by the user.  The user will just select the courses they want.  I just need to find a way to group the items.

Comment: Just use grouping as described at the end of this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337898.aspx

Comment: It seems like the grouping option just specifies a specific number of items to group together.  This will not help me because I need to group various items together by category.  For example, the first section might have 4 items, the next 6, etc. as it comes from the database.

Comment: Grouping allows you to have a variable number of items in each group. Just specify the number of columns for your layout and the ListView templates will render your bound controls.

Comment: I did something similar in ADO.NET http://codersbarn.com/post/2008/10/12/Bind-CheckBoxList-to-DataSet.aspx

Comment: How about using a placeholder control and dynamically adding checkboxlists to it? Then looping through the items on post back.

Answer (score 0):

just imagine that this is your data structure.  To do without repeaters.

```
var list = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
                           {
                               {"Name1", new List {"item1", "item2", "item3"}},
                               {"Name2", new List {"item1", "item2", "item3"}},
                               {"Name3", new List {"item1", "item2", "item3"}},
                               {"Name4", new List {"item1", "item2", "item3"}},
                               {"Name5", new List {"item1", "item2", "item3"}}
                           };

            foreach (var category in list)
            {
                var checkBoxList = new CheckBoxList
                                       {
                                           Text = category.Key
                                       };

                foreach (var value in category.Value)
                {
                    var listItem = new ListItem(value);
                    checkBoxList.Items.Add(listItem);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again to everyone for the help.  We ended up changing the requirements and a single checkboxlist will now suffice.  I think the dynamic addition of the checkboxlists to a placeholder would have worked though.